# Switch coordinates in shapefiles

Tags: shapefile, coordinates, wfs

I got some shapefiles out of a WFS service and the points and polygons are not where they supposed to be.

After taking a closer look in the data I came to the conclusion, that the X an Y coordinates are switched, which can be seen by the extents of the shapefiles.

Is there a way to switch the coordinates back?

Comment: Can you not go back to the WFS and request the data in the correct format?

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but the solution was to change an option in the WFS properties. It is called SRS Axis Order and had to be changed to the values "2, 1", where the values indicate the x- and y- axis.

Comment: @U_V , please post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 4):

QGIS has a tool called "Swap X and Y coordinates" that does exactly that:

> This algorithm swaps the X and Y coordinate values in input
>   geometries. It can be used to repair geometries which have
>   accidentally had their latitude and longitude values reversed.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i found the solution.

I forgot to activate the right Axis Order in the WFS parameters.

The solution was to change an option in the WFS properties. It is called SRS Axis Order and had to be changed to the values "2, 1", where the values indicate the x- and y- axis.

Comment: That is not an answer to the question you asked. ;)

Comment: I have ran into same issue, I am setting up this wfs https://sdmdataaccess.sc.egov.usda.gov/Spatial/SDMWGS84Geographic.wfs
but QGIS is sending Y,X but the server is configured for X,Y
Where can I find the option to inverse order in QGIS

Comment: You can check the wfs connection settings, there is an option to 'ignore axis orientation (WFS 1.1/WFS 2.0)' or rather 'inverse axis orientation'. The second option should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert everything to points, then export the points as csv and load that csv with switched coordinate-columns.

Comment: You mean convert the shapefiles with polygons to points aswell? Could work, yes.